# What is 'wow'/variants of wow?

Tags: word-choice

I've heard 'ŭaŭ', 'ho! ', and 'vaŭ'. However, I want to see if there can be a best, official translation.

Answer (score 4):

I personally typically translate this as *mirinde*, although I have often seen *ŭaŭ* as well, especially on Telegram. I'd say *ho!* is more like saying "oh!"

Comment: Uxaux! Bona respondo!

Answer (score 4):

*Ŭaŭ* is what I see the most, I also see *mirinde* as mentioned by Chuck Smith. I do not personally recall ever seeing *vaŭ*.

*Ho!* is more ambiguous, it can be good or bad.

However, I'm tempted to say it has a very slight connotation of pain or worry, as it's connected with "ho ve" and we see it in the title of "Ho, mia kor'".

When I look it up on vortaro.net, I find this:

> *ho! Interj., esprimanta tre ĝenerale la vivecon de sento: ho, kia belegeco!; ho, neesprimebla feliĉo!; ho, miaj esperoj!; ho, kia
>   malfeliĉo!; ho, terure!; **«ho» ofte signas plendan staton, de l’
>   sorto malfacilan baton**

So, it's clearly free to be used positively or negatively, but I think this definition supports the slight negative aspect. So if you're using "ho" where someone might also say "ŭaŭ", it *might* be a situation they find surprising and unpleasant. However in practical use, this nuance is probably not too influential.

*Ho* is also used when one adresses someone ("al Vi, ho potenca senkorpa Mistero!")